# Ajax.ActionLink Partial View Within Same Page (jQuery attempt also)

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax

I am having problems rendering a partial view in the same page using `@Ajax.ActionLink`. I would like to create an expandable row as pictured below:

[image: dataTable child-row]

**PersonController.cs:**

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult _SubDetails(int id)
{
    FooBarContext db = new FooBarContext();
    ContactViewModel contactViewModel = _db.Persons.Where(p => p.PersonId == id)
        .Select(c => new ContactViewModel
        {
            EmailAddress = p.EmailAddress,
            Website = p.Website
        }).FirstOrDefault();
    return PartialView(contactViewModel);
}
```

**Index.cshtml**:

```
@foreach (var item in Model.Persons.Records)
{
    <tr>
        <td>
            @*<a href="javascript:getView(@item.PersonId);">Details</a>*@
            @Ajax.ActionLink(
            "Detail of Person",
            "_SubDetails",
            new { id = item.PersonId },
            new AjaxOptions
                {
                    UpdateTargetId = "ExpandInfo",
                    InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
                    HttpMethod = "GET"
                })
            <div id="ExpandInfo"></div>
        </td>
}

<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-2.0.2.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

With `Ajax.ActionLink`, the code works fine except for the fact that upon clicking on the "Detail of Person", I am taken to another page.

As an alternative I have also attempted to accomplish the same thing with `jQuery` (without using ajax.actionlink) except my issue here is that within the partial view, I am given the entire page (the row expands but has a whole page within it).

**Index.cshtml (jQuery):**

```
@foreach (var item in Model.Person.Records)
{
    <tr>
        <td>
            <a href="javascript:getView(@item.PersonId);">Details</a>
            <div id="PersonDetail">
            </div>
}

<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function getView(personId) {
        $.ajax({
            Url: '/Person/_SubDetails/' + personId,
            contentType: "application/html; charset=utf-8",
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'html'
        }).success(function (result) {
                $('#PersonDetail').html(result);
            }).error(function (xhr, status) {
                console.log(status);
            })
    };
</script>
```

I am wondering if anyone can see what I'm missing or doing wrong in either case? Whichever one is easier to solve would really help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what I was doing wrong after doing a bit of research. That's when I realized I needed to add 2 Scripts to my project (I thought they were already included):

**jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js**

**jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js**

Finally, in my controller I added:

```
        if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
        {
            return PartialView("_SubDetails", contactViewModel);
        }

        return PartialView(contactViewModel);
```

Comment: FYI, those script are the same. The "min" version is just a light version to "minimize" size. Anyway you probably should use new Jquery version [Instructions link](https://dyball.wordpress.com/2014/04/07/partial-view-using-unobtrusive-ajax-in-mvc-5-loads-into-a-new-page/)

Answer (score 0):

Probable you may missed to set `return false.`

- Make Sure you have added the `Partial View` not the View (Comes under Mater page, So that full page will be rendered).

> **As per info:** With `Ajax.ActionLink`, the code works fine except for the fact that upon clicking on the "Detail of Person", I am taken
>   to another page.

Put `return false` once the function is called either html or Jscript function. Like Below.,

```
   function getView(personId) {
        $.ajax({
            Url: '/Person/_SubDetails/' + personId,
            contentType: "application/html; charset=utf-8",
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'html'
        }).success(function (result) { $('#PersonDetail').html(result); 
        }).error(function (xhr, status) { console.log(status); });
        return false; //  Add this line
   }
```

Or with in Html Link:

```
@*<a href="javascript:getView(@item.PersonId); return false; ">Details</a>*@
```

Comment: thanks for pointing me in the right direction. when you suggested I needed a return false line, I added a check in my controller.

Comment: I'm not getting this point `I added a check in my controller.`. Is it working as you expected?

Comment: When you suggested that I add `return false;` to my code, I realized that if I wanted the request to return something in the partial view, I would have to add that. I tried it and it didn't completely do what I needed but I figured maybe I could tweak my controller a bit and do something similar.